# unable to instantiate an application

Tags: android

I have an activity named: **AlertDialogue** under package **android.dialog**.
I have added this activity in manifest file as well,

```
  <activity
        android:name="andriod.dialog.AlertDialogue"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

While running the activity i'm getting the following error..
  What would be the issue??

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "andriod.dialog.AlertDialogue" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/android.practice-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/android.practice-2, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: Cross check your Package Name carefully.

Comment: Umm... Could it be... Typo?

Comment: Also check the filename of your Java class.

Comment: yes, i did it multiple times, even copy it and paste instead of manual entering...but no luck

Comment: Post the complete code.

Comment: "andriod".dialog.AlertDialogue. It probably is "android".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
android:name="andriod.dialog.AlertDialogue"
```

with

```
android:name="android.dialog.AlertDialogue"
```

By the way, you should'nt be using the `android.*` namespace as it is the namespace used by the framework, and there may be import clashes and other problems as well.